# Where can I find primary sources about the 1973 Arab oil embargo? Specifically from a non western perspective?

Tags: 20th-century, middle-east, political-economy, primary-source

I'm trying to compare U.S/British media portrayals (newspaper articles, speeches, etc.) to ones coming from the Middle East at the time, but it's very difficult to find the latter, especially translated into English, so that I can compare the portrayal of events. Any idea where I'd find good resources? For both perspectives, but ideally recs for primary sources from Saudi Arabia and surrounding nations.

Thank you!

Comment: When you say "primary sources", you're after mass media rather than government papers?

Comment: I'd prefer mass media, but government papers would be great as well!